# Android/PhoneGap: destroy webview when going background instead of keepRunning=false

Tags: android, cordova, webview, background-service

My PhoneGap app is 60-80MB and I wish to release as much memory as possible when going background.
My app has PhoneGap fat webview and tiny service.

WebView is used to control service that is very important.
I wish to unload as much as possible to save users battery, memory, etc.
Also fat apps are killed first.

I do not wish to run service as separate process.

Answer (score 0):

On your app's main activity which extends CordovaActivity, probably call [finish](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) inside [onStop()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStop%28%29)

Android API:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

EDIT:

For more control over the webview, use Android WebViews
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.6.0/guide_platforms_android_webview.md.html#Android%20WebViews